# Searching Prolog structures

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm interested in formulae made up from lots of conjunctions (part of a larger problem).  I want to write a program that takes something like this:

`:- get_params(conj(conj(a,b),c),X)`

and returns a list of all the parameters of the conjunctions i.e. `X=[a,b,c]`.  At the moment I can do

`:- get_params(conj(a,b),X)` to get `X=[a,b]`

using simple Prolog pattern matching but how would you go about doing things such as

`:- get_params(conj(conj(a,b),c),X)` to get `X=[a,b,c]`

It seems really simple but I've been struggling all day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all conj functors are binary:

```
get_params(X, Y, L) :- 
  get_params(X, L1),
  get_params(Y, L2),
  append(L1, L2, L).
get_params(conj(X, Y), L) :-
  get_params(X, Y, L), !.
get_params(A, [A]).
```

Comment: You have no idea how complicated I was making it, that's SO simple.  Thank you :).

Comment: You're welcome. Don't let the voodoo feeling of Prolog to throw you of your track. It's usually very simple. For example, functors are just tagged data structures, as you can see.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are describing a list, consider using DCG notation:

```
params(conj(A,B)) --> !, params(A), params(B).
params(X)         --> [X].
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(params(conj(conj(a,b),c)), Ps).
Ps = [a, b, c].
```